# Naive Bayes for Text Classification - Python 2.7 Data Structure Issue

Tags: python-2.7, data-structures, scikit-learn, nltk, naivebayes

I am having an issue training my Naive Bayes Classifier. I have a feature set and targets that I want to use but I keep getting errors. I've had a look at other people who have similar problems but I can't seem to figure out the issue. I'm sure there's a simple solution but I'm yet to find it.

Here's an example of the structure of the data that I'm trying to use to train the classifier.

```
In [1] >> train[0]
Out[1] ({
         u'profici': [False],
         u'saver': [False],
         u'four': [True],
         u'protest': [False],
         u'asian': [True],
         u'upsid': [False],
         .
         .
         .
         u'captain': [False],
         u'payoff': [False],
         u'whose': [False]
         },
         0)
```

Where train[0] is the first tuple in a list and contains:

- A dictionary of features and boolean values to indicate the presence or absence of words in document[0]
- The target label for the binary classification of document[0]

Obviously, the rest of the train list has the features and labels for the other documents that I want to classify.

When running the following code

```
from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

MNB_clf = SklearnClassifier(MultinomialNB())
MNB_clf.train(train)
```

I get the error message:

```
  TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Edit:

features are created here.  From a dataframe post_sent that contains the posts in column 1 and the sentiment classification in column 2.

```
  stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english'))
  tokenized = []
  filtered_posts = []
  punc_tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')

  #  tokenizing and removing stopwords
   for post in post_sent.post:
      tokenized = [word.lower() for word in. 
      punc_tokenizer.tokenize(post)]
      filtered = ([w for w in tokenized if not w in stopwords])
  filtered_posts.append(filtered)    

  # stemming
  tokened_stemmed = []
  for post in filtered_posts:
      stemmed = []
  for w in post:
       stemmed.append(PorterStemmer().stem_word(w))
  tokened_stemmed.append(stemmed)   

  #frequency dist
 all_words =. 
   list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(tokened_stemmed))
   frequency = FreqDist(all_words)

  # Feature selection
  word_features = list(frequency.keys())[:3000]

   # IMPORTANT PART
   #######################
   #------ featuresets creation ---------
  def find_features(list_of_posts):
       features = {}
       wrds = set(post)
           for w in word_features:
              features[w] = [w in wrds]
  return features

  # zipping inputs with targets
  words_and_sent = zip(tokened_stemmed, 
   post_sent.sentiment)

   # IMPORTANT PART 
   ##########################
  # feature sets created here
  featuresets = [(find_features(words), sentiment) for 
   words, sentiment in 
   words_and_sent]
```

Comment: The values of your feature dictionaries are all lists with a single value: `[False]`. Instead, they probably should directly be the boolean values `True`/`False`, without being wrapped in a list.

Comment: Ok so now I have a different issue..

     ` In [1] >> train[0]
      out[1] >> 

                 ([False,
                   False,
                   True,
                    ...
                   False,
                   ],
                   0)
`

Which gives me the error 

              `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems' `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the train wrong. As @lenz said in comment, remove the parentheses in the feature dict values and only use single values.

As given in the [official documentation](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html#nltk.classify.scikitlearn.SklearnClassifier.train):

> **labeled_featuresets** – A list of (featureset, label) where each
>   featureset is a dict mapping strings to either numbers, booleans or
>   strings.

But you are setting the mapping (value of key in dict) as a list.

You correct train should look like :

```
[({u'profici':False,
   u'saver':False,
   u'four':True,
   u'protest':False,
   u'asian':True,
   u'upsid':False,
   .
   .
  }, 0),
     .. 
     ..
 ({u'profici':True,
   u'saver':False,
   u'four':False,
   u'protest':False,
   u'asian':True,
   u'upsid':False,
   .
   .
  }, 1)]
```

You can take a look at more examples here: 
 - http://www.nltk.org/howto/classify.html

Comment: Thank you Vivek, that's a lot clearer. I'm not particularly good with dictionary data types. Do you have any suggestions code wise as to how I can transform it from what I have now to what I need it to be??  Cheers

Comment: @DiarmaidFinnerty How did you create the feature sets in the first place? Update your answer (or post a new one) to include the code that produces your labeled featureset, then it's going to be straight-forward to show you how to fix it.

Comment: Hi lenz, I've added the code that creates the featuresets

Comment: Hi Vivek, thanks for the help. If you feel like it you can edit you post to include the code that made it run correctly (posted as an answer below). Appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to help from both Vivek & Lenz, who explained to me the problem, I was able to reorganise my training set and thankfully it now works. Thanks guys!

The problem was very well explained in Vivek's post. This is the code that reorganised the train data into the correct format.

```
 features_targ = []

for feature in range(0,len(featuresets)):
   dict_test = featuresets[feature]
   values = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(dict_test[0].values()))
   keys = dict_test[0].keys()
   target = dict_test[1]
   dict_ion = {}
   for key in range(x,len(keys)):
     dict_ion[keys[key]] = values[key]
   features_targ.append((dict_ion,target))
```